# Setting DimensionPermission.Read to ReadAccess.None

Tags: c#, .net, ssas

I have an instance of `DimensionPermission` called `dimensionPermission` and I am trying to set the `Read` property of `dimensionPermission` to `ReadAccess.None` but I keep getting the resulting error:

The 'None' value is not valid for the 'Read' property of 'DimensionPermission'

It's not an issue to set it to `ReadAccess.Allowed` but as soon as I set it to `None`, it becomes a problem.

I've been trying to research as to why this happens but I've come up short here. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is not possible. Although AMO makes it seem as though you can set the Read permission, you actually cannot.